# Find files from large collection of small audio recordings that are close to silent

Tags: audio

I have a few thousand small 2MB audio recordings from a recording device that turns over every so often. The total amount of recording time is several days, but each file contains about 5 minutes worth. Normally, it is only meant to record audio when there is some volume happening (speech). Problem is that I had the sensitivity setting too sensitive. The result is a mix of audio files with speech in it, but with the bulk of them only having recorded a soft background hiss. I can't just "grep" the files for a bunch of zeros. I was thinking of writing a quick little Java application that loads each file, and then calculate the amount of energy in it, by simply adding the different between each sample. But I was hoping that someone might now a simple clever way of wiring together some bash/awk/play/mpg123 something anything. Possibly there exists a command line app in one of the audio tool sets that I'm not aware of yet?

Comment: Take a look at [chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint).

Comment: I don't have a way to test, but `lame`'s replaygain option looks promising. ([one use](https://www.jwz.org/hacks/video-replaygain.pl))

Comment: Have a look at `sox` with `stat` and `stats` effect. You'll need to parse the output.

Comment: This is all useful. I guess that chromaprint can perhaps help provide more accurate assessments. Lame I'm not sure can analyze a source without going through the rigmarole of compressing mp3.
But sox seems very promising. The syntax is: sox file -n stat. Out comes various things like "Volume adjustment". I'm testing now to see if the numbers are accurate enough where I can use it to select files. I might use awk to extract the number and do the comparisons. It seems I might not have to hack together a Java app after all.
Dirkt, once this works, turn it into an answer so I can vote on it.

Comment: ...Sox providing various things like Mean amplitude. It seems there's enough there to combine with something like awk.
dirkt, I'll mark your answer if you turn it into one.

Comment: Also check out `sox silence` which can trim out parts of a file with sound below a given threshold. Might be useful even in the future when you have the right trigger level. There are examples in the man page.

Comment: If you ended up writing code for this, it'd be great if you could post it as an answer.